# Enable Drilldown in highchart without modifying the series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I want to enable drilldown in highcharts, but my constraint is that I can't modify the data in the "series" property of chart. Hence I can't have the "drilldown" property set to true/any value for any item in the series.

I have tried defining "events" property in the "chart" Object. But that doesn't seem to work until and I unless I specify "drilldown" property to true for the items in the series options.

So is there a way to enable/set drilldown property to true for the chart without modifying my series? My series would just have the array of name/value pair and NO other properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize the `Chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown)) method to achieve something like this.

For example, your click listener could be:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function(e) {
                    $('#container').highcharts()
                            .addSeriesAsDrilldown(this, { data: [1,2,3] });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf8d5c1x/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Great, this works for me. Could you please let me know where did you find this documented? Thanks!

Comment: This is the API link: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown

Answer (score 1):

According to the Highcharts API there isn't, and even if there was, it's not intended to be used that way. How constrained are you in modifying the series? Can't you just loop the series in javascript and add the drilldown property dynamically before you initialize the chart?

Comment: I understand your solution, but I can't do that. It is because I am using a library which draws the chart for me. I can just supply the data (only name and value) to that library. I understand that this is the because of the limitation of the library that I am using. Hence, I am trying to find out a work around.